# VSPackage: Modify toolbar button text/tooltip at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsix, vspackage

I have been developing a Visual Studio extension as an Add-in for VS2008/2010. The new version now is to be done as a VSIX package for VS2010 only (as it has to be .NET 4 anyway), and I am having some troubles with (rather simple, I would think) UI handling.

The extension primarily consists of a toolbar with some buttons that launch various actions, forms etc., and a few that are only used as labels to display some state information. The "label" buttons themselves just show very short and concise information, while the tooltips provide more detail.

While I didn't think the whole Add-in thing was very elegant, doing this kind of stuff was pretty straightforward (though my approach may have been a little amateurish). When adding the commands to the toolbar, I would "save" the "label" buttons in specific local variables, allowing me to later set the caption and tooltip text at will.

In a VSPackage, the equivalent to *Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBarButton* appears to be *OleMenuCommand*. Finding the "label" command through the *MenuCommandService* is no problem, modifying it as needed is, however.

For the purpose of finding out how to do this, I just have a toolbar with two buttons in a group. *btnAction* is very simple; just an icon and an execute handler to change the text on the other button, no CommandFlags.
*btnLabel* looks like this in the .vsct:

```xml
<Button guid="guidVSPackageBuilderTutorialCommandSet" id="btnLabel" priority="0x0100">
    <CommandFlag>DefaultDisabled</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>DontCache</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>NoCustomize</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>TextOnly</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
        <CommandName>cmdidbtnLabel</CommandName>
        <ButtonText>btnLabel</ButtonText>
        <MenuText>btnLabel</MenuText>
        <ToolTipText>Tooltip btnLabel</ToolTipText>
    </Strings>
</Button>
```

The first problem with this is that when I use **TextChanges**, the *ToolTipText* string is ignored and the *ButtonText* is initially used for the tooltip as well.

The handler code for the action button is as follows:

```cs
private int iClickCount = 0;

protected override void btnActionExecuteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var svc = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;

    CommandID idBtnLabel = new CommandID(GuidList.guidVSPackageBuilderTutorialCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.btnLabel);
    var cmd = svc.FindCommand(idBtnLabel) as OleMenuCommand;

    cmd.Text = "Clicked " + (++iClickCount) + " times";
}
```

This changes the caption of *btnLabel* as expected, but as there is no way of explicitly specifying the tooltip (the *OleMenuCommand* object just has a *Text* property, unlike *CommandBarButton*, which has both *Caption* and *TooltipText*), the tooltip is always set to the same string as the caption. From what I understand, this is because with FindCommand() I am not actually getting the UI button, but only the underlying command, which doesn't care about tooltips.

What's even more confusing is what happens when I use the **TextChangesButton** CommandFlag instead of **TextChanges**. The button will now correctly display the tooltip text defined in the .vsct, but neither the caption nor the tooltip will change when I click the other button - though when I check the *btnLabel* command's *Text* property, it is set to what I expect ("Clicked x times"). Does **TextChangesButton** kind of "decouple" the properties of the command and the button ? If so, this is pretty much what I want (I don't care about the command, as there is nothing to execute anyway; *btnLabel* will always be disabled), but how can I access the button and its particular string properties ?

I looked through the various IVs interfaces and SVs services but couldn't find something appropriate, and the documentation (and IntelliSense help) doesn't seem to be very extensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this myself - according to someone from the VS team, the new extensibility structure does not offer ways to access these properties of controls in such detail. For what I want to achieve it will be necessary to go the old-fashioned way of getting hold of the DTE object, finding my toolbar and my controls and simply handle them as CommandBarButtons, just as I did in my Add-in.